# DateTime filtering doesn't work

Tags: c#, sql, datetime, sql-server-ce

I have an local database in Visual Studio (SQL Server Compact Edition), with a table with a few columns. One of those columns has the datatype `DateTime`. When I to insert a row I add the date/time value by using `DateTime.Now` in C#.

When I do a

```
SELECT * FROM ...
```

I see that the DateTime format is `7-5-2012 11:41`.

But now I need to do a select query with a where clause, so that the result is between certain days. I can't find a way to filter between dates/times, when I use the `DateTime.Now` function to set the between I get 0 rows back. But also when I set the between manually by setting

```
WHERE date BETWEEN '7-5-2012 00:00' AND '8-5-2012 00:00'
```

and even then I get 0 values back.

I also tried to do it with `SqlCeCommands` but gives is the same problem, 0 rows back.

Does anyone what I'm doing wrong or how I get this to work?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
"..spRis_GetListaDocs @DateFilter = '" + Convert.ToDateTime(txtDate.Text).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "'"
```

Answer (score 2):

May be you have wrong date format, you should use query command parameters:

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM ... WHERE date BETWEEN @lowb AND @highb";
command.Parameters.Add( "@lowb", SqlDbType.DateTime, new DateTime(...));
command.Parameters.Add( "@highb", SqlDbType.DateTime, new DateTime(...));
```